# Inserting and selecting data using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am working with visual studio 2010,4.0 frame work
my pages are like the following

default.aspx contain a 
textbox
button

on the click of button the data should insert into the sql database without the page being posted i.e. using jquery.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of jquery ajax function will do task for you....

Example:

[Jquery Ajax Calling functions](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/07/jquery-ajax-calling-functions.html)

[Steps to Call WCF Service using jQuery](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/.../steps-to-call-wcf-service-using-jquery.html)

Comment: @Abhishek - no one here to code for you check the links where the code is already wirttien help you to achieve you task .

Answer (score 0):

On click of the button you can make Ajax call using jQuery, which will update your table. For this on your server you will need either PageMethods or some web service, which jQuery will call.

Using PageMethods

JavaScript

```
$("#button").click(function(e){
    PageMethods.GetData(OnGetComplete);
});  

function OnGetComplete(result, userContext, methodName) {
     //Handle Result
}
```

Code Behind

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetData() {     
    return "Some random data";
}
```

For WCF and JQuery you can see the answer by Pranay Rana.
Hope this helps you.